# Need help trying to get gateway running ( mx.rpc.events::FaultEvent #0 )

Tags: amf, zend-amf

I followed the setup for http://www.zamfbrowser.org/documentation.html

When I access http://www.zamfbrowser.org/zamf_demo/gateway.php
When I access the http://localhost/gateway.php I get this error message which

```
There was an error loading the server's info.  Error: (mx.rpc.events::FaultEvent)#0
  bubbles = false
  cancelable = true
  currentTarget = (mx.rpc.remoting.mxml::RemoteObject)#1
    channelSet = (mx.messaging::ChannelSet)#2
      authenticated = false
      channelIds = (Array)#3
        [0] (null)
      channels = (Array)#4
        [0] (mx.messaging.channels::AMFChannel)#5
          authenticated = false
          channelSets = (Array)#6
          connected = false
          connectTimeout = -1
          enableSmallMessages = true
          endpoint = "http://localhot/gateway.php"
          failoverURIs = (Array)#7
          id = (null)
          mpiEnabled = false
          netConnection = (flash.net::NetConnection)#8
            client = (mx.messaging.channels::AMFChannel)#5
            connected = false
            maxPeerConnections = 8
            objectEncoding = 3
            proxyType = "none"
            uri = (null)
          piggybackingEnabled = false
          polling = false
          pollingEnabled = true
          pollingInterval = 3000
          protocol = "http"
          reconnecting = false
          recordMessageSizes = false
          recordMessageTimes = false
          requestTimeout = -1
          uri = "http://localhot/gateway.php"
          url = "http://localhot/gateway.php"
          useSmallMessages = false
      clustered = false
      connected = false
      currentChannel = (mx.messaging.channels::AMFChannel)#5
      heartbeatInterval = 0
      initialDestinationId = (null)
      messageAgents = (Array)#9
        [0] (mx.rpc::AsyncRequest)#10
          authenticated = false
          autoConnect = true
          channelSet = (mx.messaging::ChannelSet)#2
          clientId = (null)
          connected = false
          defaultHeaders = (null)
          destination = "AMF"
          id = "1D3472F3-161B-0099-5187-B4A799F5FC4C"
          priority = -1
          reconnectAttempts = 0
          reconnectInterval = 0
          requestTimeout = -1
          subtopic = ""
    concurrency = "multiple"
    convertParametersHandler = (null)
    convertResultHandler = (null)
    destination = "AMF"
    endpoint = "http://localhot/gateway.php"
    getServices = (mx.rpc.remoting.mxml::Operation)#11
      argumentNames = (Array)#12
      arguments = (Object)#13
      concurrency = "multiple"
      lastResult = (null)
      makeObjectsBindable = true
      name = "getServices"
      operationManager = (null)
      properties = (null)
      resultElementType = (null)
      resultType = (null)
      service = (mx.rpc.remoting.mxml::RemoteObject)#1
      showBusyCursor = true
    makeObjectsBindable = true
    managers = (null)
    operations = (Object)#14
      getServices = (mx.rpc.remoting.mxml::Operation)#11
    requestTimeout = -1
    showBusyCursor = true
    source = "ZendAmfServiceBrowser"
  eventPhase = 2
  fault = (mx.rpc::Fault)#15
    content = (Object)#16
    errorID = 0
    faultCode = "Client.Error.DeliveryInDoubt"
    faultDetail = "Channel disconnected before an acknowledgement was received"
    faultString = "Channel disconnected"
    message = "faultCode:Client.Error.DeliveryInDoubt faultString:'Channel disconnected' faultDetail:'Channel disconnected before an acknowledgement was received'"
    name = "Error"
    rootCause = (mx.messaging.events::ChannelEvent)#17
      bubbles = false
      cancelable = false
      channel = (mx.messaging.channels::AMFChannel)#5
      channelId = (null)
      connected = false
      currentTarget = (mx.messaging.channels::AMFChannel)#5
      eventPhase = 2
      reconnecting = true
      rejected = false
      target = (mx.messaging.channels::AMFChannel)#5
      type = "channelDisconnect"
  headers = (null)
  message = (mx.messaging.messages::ErrorMessage)#18
    body = (Object)#16
    clientId = (null)
    correlationId = "3407DB24-F4AD-C634-0E23-B4A799F60FC9"
    destination = ""
    extendedData = (null)
    faultCode = "Client.Error.DeliveryInDoubt"
    faultDetail = "Channel disconnected before an acknowledgement was received"
    faultString = "Channel disconnected"
    headers = (Object)#19
    messageId = "FB5C929F-69E4-8573-F628-B4A79AFE514B"
    rootCause = (mx.messaging.events::ChannelEvent)#17
    timestamp = 0
    timeToLive = 0
  messageId = "FB5C929F-69E4-8573-F628-B4A79AFE514B"
  statusCode = 0
  target = (mx.rpc.remoting.mxml::RemoteObject)#1
  token = (mx.rpc::AsyncToken)#20
    message = (mx.messaging.messages::RemotingMessage)#21
      body = (Array)#22
      clientId = (null)
      destination = "AMF"
      headers = (Object)#23
        DSEndpoint = (null)
        DSId = "nil"
      messageId = "3407DB24-F4AD-C634-0E23-B4A799F60FC9"
      operation = "getServices"
      source = "ZendAmfServiceBrowser"
      timestamp = 0
      timeToLive = 0
    responders = (null)
    result = (null)
  type = "fault"
```

A lot of information and I don't really know what any of it means

When accessing http://localhost/gateway.php I get the message `Zend Amf Endpoint`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to be a windows 7 issue, the same code worked on my linux server, although I didn't solve it I'll just move on.

thanks M$